# Progresscircle until activity did load

Tags: java, android, progress-bar

How can I show a progresscircle, until my whole activity did load? (Did load means, loading the activity and do some functions which need around 1-2 seconds)?

Kind Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to look at this image to get an idea:

[image]

That's an Activity's lifecycle.

A nice way to do it would be to make the ProgressBar visible at the very start of `onCreate()` and make it invisible (or `GONE`) at the end of `onResume()`. Make sure you inflate the layout before accessing it though, or you'll run into errors.

(More information about Activities: [Click here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html).)

**Edit:**

Maybe it's not a bad idea to use an `AsyncTask` for those long functions. Pass the ProgressBar to the task's constructor, then set the ProgressBar's visibility to `VISIBLE` in the `onPreExecute` function, and to `GONE` in the `onPostExecute` function.

Comment: They should usually be done via AsyncTask. Just remember to cancel the task to make sure onPostExecute does not happen after onPause.